# Prove an equation in complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

Prove an equation ($n \in N$, $z \in C$, $a \in R$):

$$ z^n +  \frac1{z^n} = 2 \cos\alpha n$$

if $$ z +  \frac1{z} = 2 \cos\alpha$$

I tried math induction, but did not solve.

Comment: Do you know Euler's formulae for the trigonometric functions in terms of the exponential function?

Comment: Only De Moivre's formula and basic complex numbers properties.

Comment: $e^{ix} = \cos x + i\sin x$, $\cos x = \frac12(e^{ix} + e^{-ix})$, $\sin x = \frac{1}{2i}(e^{ix} - e^{-ix})$. The one for $\cos$ is the one you most want here.

Comment: In book, where i faced this equation, "Euler's formulae for the trigonometric functions in terms of the exponential function" is not listed before this exercise. As i said, only De Moivre's formula. So i have to use exponential function to solve this?

Comment: @VladislavBrylinskiy: Have you learned that, for every complex number $z$, we can write $z = re^{i\theta}$ for some real numbers $r$ and $\theta$?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Only De Moivre's formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hypothesis means that
$$
z^2 - 2z\cos\alpha + 1 = 0
$$
Solve the quadratic equation:
$$
z=\cos\alpha\pm\sqrt{\cos^2\alpha-1}
$$
so
$$
z=\cos\alpha+i\sin\alpha
\quad\text{or}\quad
z=\cos\alpha-i\sin\alpha=\cos(-\alpha)+i\sin(-\alpha).
$$
Apply de Moivre's formula.

Answer (score 1):

Using de Moivre's formula $(\cos \alpha + i \sin \alpha)^n = \cos n\alpha + i \sin n\alpha$, we see that setting $z = r(\cos \alpha + i\sin \alpha)$, we have $z^{-1} = r^{-1}(\cos \alpha - i \sin \alpha)$; thus

$z + z^{-1} = r(\cos \alpha + i \sin \alpha) + r^{-1}(\cos \alpha - i \sin \alpha) = 2 \cos \alpha. \tag{1}$

This implies

$ r\cos \alpha + r^{-1}\cos \alpha = 2 \cos \alpha, \tag{2}$

as well as

$i(r\sin \alpha -r^{-1}\sin \alpha) = 0, \tag{3}$

this latter equation (3) since $2 \cos \alpha$ is real.

If $\cos \alpha \ne 0$, (2) yields

$r + r^{-1} = 2, \tag{4}$

or

$(r - 1)^2 = r^2 - 2r + 1 = 0; \tag{5}$

$r = 1$ and $z = \cos \alpha + \sin \alpha$; then $z^n = \cos (n\alpha) + i\sin (n\alpha)$,  $z^{-n} = \cos (-n\alpha) + i\sin (-n\alpha) = \cos (n\alpha) - i\sin (n\alpha)$, so

$z^n + z^{-n} = 2 \cos n \alpha \tag{6}$

in this case.

In the event that  $\cos \alpha = 0$, we have $\sin \alpha \ne 0$, and from (3) we infer

$r \sin \alpha = r^{-1} \sin \alpha, \tag{7}$

whence

$r^2 = 1, \tag{8}$

implying $r = 1$ since $r > 0$.  Thus we still have $z = \cos \alpha + i\sin \alpha$ and (6) still follows as in the case $\cos \alpha \ne 0$.  I credit Daniel Littlewood's comment for making clear to me the utility of equation (3) in this context.

Well, I *hope* that helps.  Cheers,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are familiar with the formula $z^{n}=(\cos(\alpha)+i\sin(\alpha))^{n}=\cos(n\alpha)+i\sin(n\alpha)$ at least for integers $n$, then you can see that$$z^{n}+z^{-n}=\cos(n\alpha)+i\sin(n\alpha)+\cos(-n\alpha)+i\sin(n\alpha)$$
Since $\cos$ is even and $\sin$ is odd, this simplifies to your result.

Comment: As i understand, $$z^n + z^{-n} = r^n (\cos (na) + i\sin (na)) + r^{-n}(\cos (-na) + i\sin (-na))$$

Comment: If $z+1/z=2\cos \alpha$ then $r=1$.

Comment: Can you please prove this last statement, and i am done.

Comment: Let $z=re^{i\theta}$, so that $z+1/z=r\cos\theta+ir\sin\theta+1/r\cos\theta-i1/r\sin\theta=2\cos\alpha$ is purely real, meaning $r\sin\theta=1/r \sin\theta$. Thus, either $\sin\theta=0$, so $z$ is a real number, or $r^{2}=1$ so $r=1$ (note $r>0$). Is this sufficient?